New Customer Register Issue in magento 2.4.7.It throws an error "There is already an account with this email address."
I have upgraded the magento 2.4.0 to 2.4.7.
When I want to register the customer with the new unique distinct values, then it is throwing the error message:
"There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, click here to get your password and access your account."

This image shows the error message when tried to create the new customer account.

The error is coming from customerAlreadyExistsErrorMessage
that is in this file
vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php
try changing to this and then register will gave an error why is it happening
catch (StateException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->messageManager->addComplexErrorMessage(
                'customerAlreadyExistsErrorMessage',
                [
                    'url' => $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword'),
                ]
            );
        }



Didnot Worked for me. Can you help me with Other solutions

changing to above code gave me detail of error, why can't yours?
image attached in answer

use xdebug to identify quickly why you get this error. This will be fastest way to identify and solve your issue I believe. I believe the use already exists. Try checking from admin once

Sorry to say but It didnot give me any other errors.
I have added the unique emails but still same issue exists..nth in the console and network tab even.
